# Remove audio track in QuickTime 10?

Tags: quicktime, video-editing

In previous versions of QuickTime you could remove the audio track and save the file. This function appears to have been removed in QuickTime 10.

Is it still possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Audio tracks can be removed from QuickTime movies using Automator.

This workflow

[image: as shown here]

will remove the audio track from all the files in the Movies folder on the desktop.

**Note this will remove the audio tracks in situ so please take a copy of them if you want to keep the audio.**

Comment: Note that this will disable the audio track temporarily only. It doesn't completely remove the audio. You have to export the video afterwards, then the audio is gone.

Comment: When I try to run this work flow ı am getting this error `The action “Enable or Disable Tracks” encountered an error: “NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread!”`

Comment: This doesn't work. I get the same error as above (interestingly there is no error when doing it the other way around, i.e. removing the video and saving just the audio... But that's not what we want.)

Comment: @LinusGeffarth export how ?

Comment: @codebased this is from a while ago, but I think I meant you need to export it from QuickTime directly in the menu bar.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a [demultiplexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demultiplexer_(media_file)) or demux utility. Which one to use can depend on your specific file container format.

- [Quicktime Player 7](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201288) had the features you remember for demuxing individual tracks. Apple claims it can still be installed. You may need the Pro feature set though I'm not sure they would sell you a key anymore.
- [Subler](https://subler.org) is a muxer that will do MP4 files. It can demux as well.
- [Squared5](http://www.squared5.com) claims to do the job for MOV files.
- [FFMPegX](https://www.ffmpegx.com) provides a Mac OS GUI for many media libraries that can mux/demux most anything.

Comment: FYI, the command that allows you to delete the audio track in Quicktime Player 7 is Window>Show Movie Properties. Unfortunately, that *is* a Pro feature, and Apple no longer sells QuickTime Pro. Fortunately, if you do happen to have a key, it will still work, as there's no online verification of the registration code. Just remember to quit and restart the app after you register.

Answer (score 0):

[Avidemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net) is an opensource tool for Mac/Win/Linux that does the job. Load your file, and in the Audio menu pick *Choose Audio Track*, then disable the audio track, and save to a new file. Make sure Video stays on *copy*.